# Are the final fantasy mangas spinoffs or retellings?

Tags: final-fantasy

I have played several of the Final Fantasy games and know that many of them have manga counterparts.

Having finished the games, I wouldn't overly want to read a retelling of the story I spent hours grinding through. However, If they are spin off stories I would be interested in reading them as I enjoy the interesting characters and fantasy world.

Do the manga series retell the games' stories or do they have alternate content in them?

Comment: Can you provide some series as examples? Not all series are created equal.

Comment: I came across the ff12 manga recently, but I'm pretty sure 2,3,4 have mangas also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are indeed allot of manga/novel/manwha adaptions of Final fantasy games,anime and movies and there are indeed some with alternate content to the already known storys or even totaly new storys. [As found on final fantasy released media wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Final_Fantasy_media)

> Many Final Fantasy games have been adapted as novels and manga series. With the advent of the Internet, web novels and digital publishing have also become common. These stories act as companion pieces, offering an interpretation of the game's events or expanding the plot of the games by depicting additional scenarios.

## Based on stuff

- **Final Fantasy II Mumu no Meikyu**, Is the 
  Novelization of Final Fantasy II written by Kenji Terada
- **Yūkyū no Kaze Densetsu Final Fantasy III**, Manga adaptation of Final Fantasy III by Yū Kinutani (art) and Kenji Terada (story)
- **Final Fantasy: The Spirits Within**, Novelization of Final Fantasy: The Spirits Within by John Vornhol
- **Final Fantasy Crystal Chronicles ~Hatenaki Sora no Mukō ni~**, Manga adaptation of Final Fantasy Crystal Chronicles by Ryunosuke Ichikawa (three volumes)
- **Final Fantasy IV**, Two-volume novelization of Final Fantasy IV
- **Final Fantasy IV: The After**, Novelization of Final Fantasy IV: The After Years
- **Adventure Log**, Official Final Fantasy XI webcomic
- **Final Fantasy XII**, Manga adaptation of Final Fantasy XII by Gin Amou
- **Final Fantasy Crystal Chronicles Ring of Fates 4 Komaansoroji Komikku**, Manga adaptation of Final Fantasy Crystal Chronicles: Ring of Fates (2 volumes)
- **Final Fantasy XIII Episode Zero: Promise**, Series of web novels written by Jun Eishima and first published on the official Japanese Final Fantasy XIII website, depicting the thirteen days leading up to the events of the game

## Unique content

- **Sō no Kizuna**, A side story to Final Fantasy: Unlimited
- **Final Fantasy: Unlimited After**, A series of web novels published on the official Japanese Final Fantasy: Unlimited website, which continue the story of the anime
- **On the Way to a Smile**, Collection of two novellas, "Case of Denzel" and "Case of Tifa", set in Final Fantasy VII's continuity, written by Kazushige Nojima and published in the book Final Fantasy VII: Advent Children Prologue
- **Final Fantasy XI ~The Out of Orders~**, Manhwa set in the Final Fantasy XI continuity, by Kim Byung Jin (art) and Kim Sungjae (story)
- **Final Fantasy XI**, Series of novels set in the Final Fantasy XI continuity, written by Miyabi Hasegawa

Comment: I might have made some mistakes with the split up to unique/known content as I did not play all Final Fantasys. If so feel free to move them through editing.